# How to receive data through props React and send it back?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm getting a placeholder value through props in my input component and I need to send the input value back to the main class. I'm using React but I'm not getting it. Follow my code.... The value I need to send is the value of 'usuario'

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { EntradaDados } from './styled';


const PesqDados = ({placeholder, usuario}) => {

const [usuario, SetUsuario] = useState('')

const setValor =(e)=>{
    SetUsuario(e.target.value);
}
console.log(usuario);

    return(
        <EntradaDados 
            onChange={setValor}
            placeholder={placeholder}
            >
        </EntradaDados>
 );
}

export default PesqDados;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Hook : Send data from child to parent component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55726886/react-hook-send-data-from-child-to-parent-component)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a callback prop (`onUsuarioChange`) to your `PesqDados` component and call it with the new `usuario`. You have two options:

- Call it from a `useEffect` with `usuario` as dependency (assuming `usuario` could get updated from somewhere other than `setValor`.
- Call it from `setValor`, assuming that's the only place where `usuario` is going to get updated from.

This is how this should look:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { EntradaDados } from './styled';

const PesqDados = ({
  placeholder,
  usuario,
  onUsuarioChange
}) => {

  const [usuario, setUsuario] = useState('');

  // Option 1:
  useEffect(() => {
    onUsuarioChange(usuario);
  }, [usuario]);

  const setValor = (e) => {
    const nextUsuario = e.target.value;

    setUsuario(nextUsuario);

    // Option 2:
    onUsuarioChange(nextUsuario);
  };

  return (
    <EntradaDados 
      onChange={ setValor }
      placeholder={ placeholder } />
  );
}

export default PesqDados;
```

Answer (score 0):

After studying properly, I found that I don't need to implement the function in the component page. I just needed to create a hook that calls the component's OnChange property on the component's page and then create a function just in the place where the component is installed. In this case, App.js.

Page Component....

```js
const PesqDados = ({placeholder, Dados}) => {

    return(
        <EntradaDados 
            onChange={Dados}
            placeholder={placeholder}
            >
        </EntradaDados>
 );
}

export default PesqDados;
```

Page App.js

```js
function App() {

  
  const [usuario, SetUsuario] = useState('Aguardando Dados...')
  
  const setValor =(e)=>{
    SetUsuario(e.target.value);
  }  
  
  const teste = ()=>{
    alert("O usuário digitado foi : "+usuario)
  };
  


  return (
    <>
      <div className='divRepos'>

          <div className='bloco'>
            <div className='pesquisar'>                        
              <p>{usuario}</p>
              <PesqDados 
               placeholder={"Digite um username válido"} 
               Dados={setValor}
              />
              
              <Button nomeBotao={"Pesquisar Perfil"}
                      onClick={teste}/>
            </div>
...
```

Comment: This worked as I wanted